# Ademco Contact-ID over TCP/IP

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, raspberry-pi

I got an home alarm system that i control using php script (arm/disarm, etc.) but the alarm report using this is not very reliable. I have learned that the system support an Ademco Contact-ID style report using TCP/IP. So far i have only found examples using PSTN og VOIP.

Is there some free open source Ademco Contact-ID server out there, that I can run on my Raspberry Pi? Or socks server? Or a script i can run, that can handle CID over IP?

Answer (score 2):

What I found out about *Contact ID over IP* (by trying) is:

- It uses TCP
- It expects an ACK symbol as response (at least mine does)

The most basic script for just collecting events then would be:

```
while true ; do nc -l 1337 < ack.txt >> contact_id.log ; done
```

`ack.txt` here contains an ack-character

Comment: I am trying to do something similar for my alarm, but I cannot find information about what should be sent back in the ack.txt file. I could not find any official info on this protocol over TCP. Anyone has useful hints?

Comment: the ack.txt in my approach contains the character ACK. This is a "control character" just like "A" is a printable character. Search for "ASCII table".

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be a direct answer, as I have not found any on CID over TCP either, I may have an alternate solution. I set up my RPi in the same manner except I am using the GPIOs to detect changes in the alarm systems output relays. I have programmed my alarm panel to trip specific onboard relays on alarms. I monitor these relays with the RPi. I also have the ability to arm/disarm via the alarm panels keyswitch zones (off relays on the RPi).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's still any interest in this since it's so long ago, but I wrote a simple CSV-IP server a while back that processes notifications from an alarm system in Contact ID format (which is what CSV-IP is a TCP wrapper for) and decodes and prints out the info that's being sent.

One comment from a previous reply, the spec doesn't specify an ACK symbol but requires that you echo the entire message back to the sender.  You can send an ACK and you'll get a retry of the original message which is required by the spec so it appears that the ACK has been processed, but it's just the retry mechanism being triggered.